# Extract a substring from a string in R when coming across a special character

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract the base name (U+...) for all emoji's in a string. I currently have a data frame with a column of Instagram messages (For such reasons I can't post on here for ethical reasons. However I will post a self generated one.)

I want to extract all emoji's from the messages string.

So far I have been successful in using gsub to extract a single emoji from a single piece of text. For example:

```
    gsub(".*[<]([^.]+)[>].*", "\\1", "I know <U+0001F621<U+0001F923>")
```

This gives me the last emoji :

```
    [1] "U+0001F923"
```

However I'd like it to catch all emoji's in the string.

like this:

```
    [1] "U+0001F923"  [2] "U+0001F621"
```

Furthermore I have tried to use this gsub code to extract the data from a 2 column data frame.  (Below is a snippet from a much larger data frame)

df:

```
    name                     value
    <chr>                    <chr>
    Participant1             instahandle1   
    Participant2             instahandle2   
    conversation.sender      instahandle2   
    conversation.created_at  2019-03-24T19:08:25.632223+00:00   
    conversation.text        I know <U+0001F923><U+0001F923>x   
    conversation.sender      instahandle1   
    conversation.created_at  2019-03-24T19:04:01.042261+00:00   
    conversation.text        Me too! it was cool    
    conversation.sender      instahandle2   
    conversation.created_at  2019-03-24T19:03:42.065983+00:00

    gsub(".*[<]([^.]+)[>].*", "\\1", df$value)
```

However this just retrieves.

```
    [1] "instahandle1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [2] "instahandle2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    [3] "instahandle2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    [4] "2019-03-24T19:08:25.632223+00:00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    [5] "I know \U0001f923\U0001f923x"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    [6] "instahandle1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [7] "2019-03-24T19:04:01.042261+00:00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    [8] "Me too! it was cool"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    [9] "instahandle2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    [10] "2019-03-24T19:03:42.065983+00:00"
```

I would like it to extract every emoji and nothing else.
like this:

```
     [1] "U+0001F923"  [2] "U+0001F621"
```

Comment: Try `regmatches(df$value, gregexpr("<\\K[^<>]+", df$value, perl=TRUE))`

Comment: I tried that. However I just get a long output list of these: [[1]]
character(0), [[2]]
character(0).

Comment: Strange. See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/c0OCTZ). Could you please create a subset of your real data (using `dput`) and share in the question?

Comment: It looks like you have no `<U+` and `>` with alnum chars in between, there are real Unicode chars. Check [this approach](https://ideone.com/p4fLyZ)

Comment: If it is not what you need, try to load `library(stringr)` and then use `str_extract_all(df$value, "(?<=<)[^<>]+")`

Comment: Please share the result of `dput(head(df,10))`

Comment: Also, try [this code](https://rextester.com/KEEINZ30285).

Comment: Brilliant! The first demo seems to have worked! Thank you. ---> x <- "I know \U0001F621\U0001F923s"
regmatches(x, gregexpr("[^[:ascii:]]+", x, perl=TRUE))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- "I know \U0001F621\U0001F923s"
regmatches(x, gregexpr("[^[:ascii:]]+", x, perl=TRUE))
## => [[1]]
##    [1] ""
```

This code extracts all non-ASCII char chunks from the input. See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/YbjAUz).

Since `[:ascii:]` character class is not POSIX compliant, `perl=TRUE` is required.

If you want to extract only emojis separately use

```
emoji_rx <- "[\\x{1f300}-\\x{1f5ff}\\x{1f900}-\\x{1f9ff}\\x{1f600}-\\x{1f64f}\\x{1f680}-\\x{1f6ff}\\x{2600}-\\x{26ff}\\x{2700}-\\x{27bf}\\x{1f1e6}-\\x{1f1ff}\\x{1f191}-\\x{1f251}\\x{1f004}\\x{1f0cf}\\x{1f170}-\\x{1f171}\\x{1f17e}-\\x{1f17f}\\x{1f18e}\\x{3030}\\x{2b50}\\x{2b55}\\x{2934}-\\x{2935}\\x{2b05}-\\x{2b07}\\x{2b1b}-\\x{2b1c}\\x{3297}\\x{3299}\\x{303d}\\x{00a9}\\x{00ae}\\x{2122}\\x{23f3}\\x{24c2}\\x{23e9}-\\x{23ef}\\x{25b6}\\x{23f8}-\\x{23fa}]"
x <- "I know \U0001F621\U0001F923s"
regmatches(x, gregexpr(emoji_rx, x, perl=TRUE))
## => [[1]]
##    [1] "" ""
## Or, to get them as single chunks
emoji_rx <- "[\\x{1f300}-\\x{1f5ff}\\x{1f900}-\\x{1f9ff}\\x{1f600}-\\x{1f64f}\\x{1f680}-\\x{1f6ff}\\x{2600}-\\x{26ff}\\x{2700}-\\x{27bf}\\x{1f1e6}-\\x{1f1ff}\\x{1f191}-\\x{1f251}\\x{1f004}\\x{1f0cf}\\x{1f170}-\\x{1f171}\\x{1f17e}-\\x{1f17f}\\x{1f18e}\\x{3030}\\x{2b50}\\x{2b55}\\x{2934}-\\x{2935}\\x{2b05}-\\x{2b07}\\x{2b1b}-\\x{2b1c}\\x{3297}\\x{3299}\\x{303d}\\x{00a9}\\x{00ae}\\x{2122}\\x{23f3}\\x{24c2}\\x{23e9}-\\x{23ef}\\x{25b6}\\x{23f8}-\\x{23fa}]+"
regmatches(x, gregexpr(emoji_rx, x, perl=TRUE))
## => [[1]]
##    [1] ""
```

See [this online R demo](https://ideone.com/7fi9Eb).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Turns out you'll have to escape the backslashes as well:

`<(U\\+\\S*?)> /g` Try [here](https://spannbaueradam.shinyapps.io/r_regex_tester/) it works

This captures all the emojis as expected. An emoji is assumed to be enclosed in angular brackets and begin with `U+`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qDKfTQ/1)

Comment: This works nicely in that demo but it does not seem to like it when I run it in R, I tried using this in r as: gsub("<(U\+\S*?)> /g", "I know <U+0001F621><U+0001F923>") and I got the error: Error: '\+' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""<(U\+"

Comment: Are you setting `perl = TRUE`?

Comment: Try now. The backslashes have a special meaning and need to be escaped as well.

Comment: I tried with your new edit, gsub("<(U\\+\\S*?)> /g","\\1", "I know <U+0001F621><U+0001F923>", perl = TRUE). However its just reprinting the whole string. Output: [1] "I know <U+0001F621><U+0001F923>"

Comment: You need to use the capture groups.

Comment: Apologies, I'm still very much a amateur coder. What capture groups?

Comment: On the right hand side in [this](https://regex101.com/r/qDKfTQ/1) link, in green color -> Group 1. You access it via `\1`

Comment: I found a way of getting around it if you look at the comment by Wiktor Stribiżew